# How to do a full bleed background image that scales with resolution in css/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Full Screen Background Image in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278470/full-screen-background-image-in-firefox)

See this: http://www.ingress.com/

How do you do something like this that will look right in any monitor resolution?  In the Ingress site, it looks like even the size of the content (the iphone image for example) scales as you shrink or grow the resolution/window size.

Comment: [`@media` queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy, but it's CSS3 and not supported on old browsers. Use [`background-size:cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) or `background-size:contain` in your CSS.

[CSS-tricks has an article](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) with other, more robust solutions.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks @Yazan...the css-tricks article is also very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

is that what you're looking for :

```
<body style="background:url(image.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed">
```

Comment: And `background-size:cover;`